# React Native Posting Instagram Story with URL link under Username (Example: View in SoundCloud)

Tags: react-native, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-story, react-native-share

I'm working on a react native app using the react-native-share package to share an image to Instagram. I'm able to share the image to Instagram on iOS, but would like to display a url at the top left corner to tell others to view this post in our website.

It seems some apps can do this already like Spotify or Netflix or Soundcloud.

I've tried to use the package's Share.shareSingle method with the attributionURL: 'https://google.com', however, this doesn't display anything at the top.

Not found in the documentation either:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories/

Does anyone know how to implement this using the React Native package similar to the picture here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iU7tB.jpg

And please provide documentation and a code example if possible, or how the link should be formatted. Thank you!